# Can i use 4 bit, 8 bit version of transformers translation model?

Tags: python, deep-learning, huggingface-transformers, quantization

Are quantized versions available for other transformer models beyond LLMs, specifically for translation models? I'm looking for information about the following models:

This models:

- https://huggingface.co/Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-zh-en
- https://huggingface.co/Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-tc-big-it-en
- https://huggingface.co/t5-small
- https://huggingface.co/facebook/nllb-200-distilled-600M

I've conducted online searches but haven't found a definitive answer on the availability of quantized versions for these models.

Comment: Quantized versions are heavily re-engineered from the original models (in FP16 or FP32). One of the pioneer lib/package for doing so is [bitsandbytes](https://github.com/TimDettmers/bitsandbytes), initialized by Facebook Research.

Comment: I will check it out.

Comment: You can try the native dynamic quantization too https://github.com/alvations/lightyear/blob/main/lightyear/utils.py but YMMV

Answer (score 0):

It might not work for every model, but you can try 8-bit quantization with native pytorch, https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/dynamic_quantization.html like this:

```
import gc

import torch
from torch import nn


def quantize_model(model: nn.Module, precision=torch.qint8, layers={nn.LayerNorm, nn.Linear, nn.Dropout}):
    model_q = torch.quantization.quantize_dynamic(
        model, layers, dtype=precision)
    del model
    gc.collect()
    return model_q
```

Then:

```
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("facebook/nllb-200-distilled-600M")
model = quantize_model(self.model)
```

There's a few more examples for 8-bits quantization on https://github.com/alvations/lightyear/tree/main/lightyear/translators

---

But with more modern, post 2022 ChatGPT models, I'll suggest looking at bitsandbytes, https://huggingface.co/blog/4bit-transformers-bitsandbytes